# How to find in which BAR register of PCI config space ,the corresponding device address is present

Tags: linux-device-driver

there are bar0 to bar5 in pci config space for every device.and in boot time the corresponding device is addressed to processor address space and that info is present i bar registers of that device. so in which bar register the corresponding device address is present.and and which bar register indicate weather the device is memory mapped or i/o mapped.
if possible please share a simple PCI serial driver code.

Comment: 1. In any bar. 2. Least significant bits in the bar.

Comment: Then why do we need 6 bar registers

Comment: Perhaps someone should read a PCI architecture handbook.

Comment: sir please tell me that how to know in which BAR register our corresponding device address is present

Comment: I dunno. You have to read a book and check your query with hw engineers / hardware vendors.